# Loop through items in a folder

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm trying to export Outlook messages with tables to Excel.

All mails are in the same mailbox, have the same subject and can contain multiple tables with varying number of rows.

I get the first mail, but it won't loop through the entire mailbox.

```
Option Explicit

Sub impToExcel()

' point to the desired email
Const strMail As String = "jonfo@company.com"
Dim oApp As Outlook.Application
Dim Nsp As Namespace
Dim Fldr As MAPIFolder
Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim Var As Variant

Set oApp = New Outlook.Application
Set Nsp = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Set Fldr = Nsp.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Svar")
Set oMail = Fldr.Items(Fldr.Items.Count)

' get html table from email object
Dim oHTML As MSHTML.HTMLDocument: Set oHTML = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim oElColl As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
With oHTML
    .body.innerHTML = oMail.HTMLBody
    Set oElColl = .getElementsByTagName("table")
End With

'import in Excel
Dim x As Long, y As Long

For Each Var In Fldr.Items
    For x = 0 To oElColl(0).Rows.Length - 1
        For y = 0 To oElColl(0).Rows(x).Cells.Length - 1
            Range("A1").Offset(x, y).Value = oElColl(0).Rows(x).Cells(y).innerText
        Next y
    Next x
Next Var

Set oApp = Nothing
Set Fldr = Nothing
Set oMail = Nothing
Set oHTML = Nothing
Set oElColl = Nothing
End Sub
```